# Visualisation of ellipse as conic section

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I am sorry if this question sounds stupid, but I have this doubt in mind ever since I was a child.

We know ellipses are symmetrical figures, having 2 axes of symmetry.

We know that an ellipse is generated from a cone when a plane cuts it at some angle say $\theta$ ( see [conic section](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicSection.html)) Now the cone is not same shape at both ends (my doubt), so a perfect ellipse shouldn't be formed from cone as it would result in a distorted ellipse with only one axis of symmetry (my thinking)

I think that an ellipse that is a [cylindric section](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricSection.html) is seemingly more symmetrical than the ellipse that is a conic section

How can I be satisfied that conic section ellipse is truly an ellipse? I think we need to solve the cone with a plane equation right?

Also, *How can both cone and cylinder generate **perfect ellipse?***

[image]

*Here in this figure, to me the ellipse looks imperfect. But really it isn't!*

### EDIT

Recently (August 1, 2018) a new video was added by **3B1B** adressing this very question, and he used dandelin sphere proof to show **equivalence of Thumbtack construction and slicing cone/ cylinder construction**. Watch here: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQa_tWZmlGs)

Comment: The axes of symmetry of the ellipse are not necessarily the axes of symmetry of the cone. Think about a conic section with angle almost $90$ degrees to the base.

Comment: @uniquesolution Yes I get what you say, but I find it rather hard to believe. *How can both cone and cylinder generate perfect ellipse*?

Comment: You see, beliefs and "how-can" questions are really hard to settle.

Comment: @uniquesolution An ellipse, as tought in class was locus of P such that its distance from Focus  S was less than its distance from directrix M. How can we be sure that this conic section is *ellipse*?

Comment: That's a very old question that has some very old answers, don't you think?

Comment: May be this helps :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres

Comment: @samjoe But did you not observe or realize at end of minor axis the focus/ directrix combination  $(F1,D1) $ that you were so far talking about suddenly switched  to$(F2,D2) ?$  And also that either combination is equally holding good?

Comment: That figure doesn't depict the ellipse of intersection: it depicts a projection onto the surface of your monitor. And the projection, incidentally, looks like a perfect ellipse to my eye.

Comment: I was trying to figure out what  OP meant by *distance from focus < distance to directrix M*  in the  intersection plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**:

The intersection of a plane and a quadric (among which cones and cylindres) is a conic, described by a quadratic equation 
$$ax^2+by^2+2cxy+2dx+2ey+f=0.$$

The conics are 4-way symmetrical curves. This is proven by the fact that the equation can be reduced to the form

$$\lambda x^2+\mu y^2=\nu$$ by translation and rotation (except in a few degenerate cases).

---

In polar coordinates, a conic can be represented by the equation

$$r=\frac l{1+e\cos\theta}.$$

By evenness of the cosine function, you expect the curve to by symmetrical around the axis $y=0$. But there is another, unexpected, symmetry. Indeed, we can rewrite

$$r^2=(l-er\cos\theta)^2$$ or in Cartesian coordinates

$$x^2+y^2=l^2-2ex+e^2x^2$$ then by completing the square

$$(1-e^2)\left(x+\frac{e}{1-e^2}\right)^2+y^2=l^2+\frac{e^2}{1-e^2}.$$

So the other symmetry axis is $$x=-\frac e{1-e^2}.$$

[image]

Again, this is due to the degree of the algebraic equation.

Comment: Admittedly, this doesn't help geometric intuition a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It explains a lot, but I am currently trying to find a procedure to convert a second degree expression like one you described into the reduced form as you mentioned, like in a question I asked some time back **[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077228/how-can-we-factorise-a-general-second-degree-expression)**. I also don't know from where the $\Delta$ came into play, and if you have knowledge on the method of factoring by rotation and translation, please do share! Thank you!

Comment: @samjoe: maybe this: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1769439/65203

Comment: Thanks that does help  alot. I can handle translation, but rotation is difficult for me, i can identify a standard curve, but not any general curve, but your answer helped a lot.

Comment: There were some attempts to address the geometric intuition here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184505/why-ellipse-is-a-conic-section

Comment: A video by 3B1B adressing similar question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQa_tWZmlGs